# Solve the following congruence for x (Modulo Question)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need help in a question that I'm having a hard time understanding... It is asking to determine the congruence for $x$ and expressing the answer in the range 0-1000:

$$ 200 . x = 13 \pmod{1001} $$

I'm not sure what to do... So far I have determined that the inverse of $ 200  \pmod{1001} $ is $ -5 $ but I'm not sure how to find a range of congruency for $x$...

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Finding that inverse was the hardest part. Well done! Now multiply the congruence by $-5$. What do you get?

Comment: It would be $-1000 = -65 ( mod 1001 ) $ How does that help determine congruency?

Comment: You get $-1000x\equiv -65$. Because $-5$ is the inverse of $200$, you get that $200\cdot(-5)\equiv1$, so the congruence actually then reads $x\equiv -65$. Better, right?

Comment: It is just like solving ordinary linear equations. Say, you have the equation
$$\frac{x}{-5}=13.$$ You multiply both side by $-5$. The new thing with congruences is to get used to thinking of $200$ as $1/(-5)$ (when working modulo $1001$).

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply both sides by $-5$ and you'll get $$x \equiv -65 \pmod{1001} \equiv -65 + 1001\pmod{1001} \equiv 936\pmod{1001}$$

Comment: Why did you add 1001 and -65? Where did that 1001 come from?

Comment: @tommark Because you want the answer to be between $0$ and $1000$. Hope you know that $a \equiv b (mod \; c)$ iff $c$ divides $a-b$?

Comment: Whether you need to add 1001 depends upon how you are defining "modulo".  Some people define "x mod n" to be a number equal to the remainder when x is divided by n.  That is, of course, a number from 0 to n-1.  Others define as the **set** of all numbers that have the same remainder when divided by n.  Of course, if you do that then it simplifies things a great deal to select, as "representative" of the set, the smallest non-negative number in the set which goes back to a number from 0 to n-1.